# Can I uninstall and reinstall ONLY Spyder, but not the entire Anaconda framework?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

Spyder has been working fine for me, for quite some time.  Now, all of a sudden, I am seeing this image, and nothing else.

[image]

I tried '`spyder --reset`' of course, and that didn't work.  I tried everything from this link.

https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Troubleshooting-Guide-and-FAQ

I'm wondering what is the easiest way to move forward here?  Should I completely uninstall and reinstall Anaconda?  Is there some way to uninstall and reinstall ONLY Spyder, but leave Anaconda in tact?  If that is actually an option, that seems easier to me, rather than going through the overhead of uninstalling and reinstalling the entire Anaconda framework.  Thoughts?  Suggestions?  Thanks for the look!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up uninstalling and reinstalling the entire Anaconda framework and everything works fine now.  In the interest of time, and convenience, I think this was the best thing to do.  It seems like everything is integrated so tightly, this is the ONLY thing to do.  I'm pretty sure it's by design!  It's fine!  It works 99.9999999% of the time, or more!  Totally fine with me!!

Comment: so you tested 1000000000 times and once it didn't go well ;) ?

Comment: LOL!  Something like that, but I am rounding off the difference and applying common sense as well.  Thanks to all!!

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to fix the spyder kernels and some issues with anaconda setuptools
so from the anaconda prompt I tried:

conda update setuptools

spyder --reset

and It worked for me!

I don't see anymore the errors in Spyder console about the kernels.

Comment: This will delete all your Spyder workspace setup (file history, interface customization, ...). Do it carefully.

Answer (score 0):

By uninstalling Anaconda 3 2022.05, and re-installing Anaconda 3 2022.10, Spyder updated to 5.1.5 to 5.2.2, not to the latest 5.3.3 but at least my bug in kernel is gone. Also, I tried to update to 5.3.3 but it didn't update again - stuck while installing.

[First, it looks like completing the update, but...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWh1U.png)
[Stuck in this screen for 2 hours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnq7v.png)